# Kак в Android -е отправить логи по email -у при падения приложения?

Tags: android

Kак в Android -е отправить логи по email -у при падения приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Можно при старте главного `Activity` записывать состояние приложения, а при нормальном выходе сбрасывать это состояние. Если приложение упало, то состояние не сбросится и при последующем старте можно будет отправить email.

Но крайне рекомендую для подобных действий использовать системы тестирования приложений. Например:

1. [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/#s)
2. [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/)